# google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError when instantiating a TensorFlow model with Python

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. I have: Python 2.7.12, Python 3.5.2, tensorflow 1.2.0-rc1, protobuf 3.3.0.

I want to follow this [tutorial](https://gist.github.com/martinwicke/6838c23abdc53e6bcda36ed9f40cff39).

But I think my problem can be evidenced more succinctly with this test.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[])
```

I cannot instantiate regressor. I get (full Traceback at the end):

> google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 48:12 : Message type "tensorflow.AttrValue" has no field named "5".

Same goes in [21] of the tutorial. Same goes with python2 and python3. Same goes if I use LinearClassifier instead of LinearRegressor.

Any idea about what I am doing very wrong?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 2, in 
>       regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[])
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py",
>   line 53, in **getattr**
>       module = self._load()
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py",
>   line 42, in _load
>       module = importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in
>   import_module
>       **import**(name)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/**init**.py",
>   line 35, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib import image
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/**init**.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.image.python.ops.single_image_random_dot_stereograms
>   import single_image_random_dot_stereograms
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/image/python/ops/single_image_random_dot_stereograms.py",
>   line 26, in 
>       "_single_image_random_dot_stereograms.so"))
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py",
>   line 55, in load_op_library
>       ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py",
>   line 84, in load_op_library
>       exec(wrappers, module.**dict**)
>
> File "", line 248, in
>
> File "", line 114, in _InitOpDefLibrary
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 481, in Merge
>       descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 535, in MergeLines
>       return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 568, in MergeLines
>       self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 583, in _ParseOrMerge
>       self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 684, in _MergeField
>       merger(tokenizer, message, field)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 773, in _MergeMessageField
>       self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 684, in _MergeField
>       merger(tokenizer, message, field)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 773, in _MergeMessageField
>       self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 684, in _MergeField
>       merger(tokenizer, message, field)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 773, in _MergeMessageField
>       self._MergeField(tokenizer, sub_message)
>
> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/text_format.py",
>   line 652, in _MergeField
>       (message_descriptor.full_name, name))

Comment: I don't think that there is anything you are doing wrong. I can confirm this error with a fresh Tensorflow r1.2 from GitHub build on Ubuntu 17.04 and Python 3.5.3

Comment: On Tensorflow r1.1 `regressor = tf.contrib.learn.LinearRegressor(feature_columns=[])` asserts because the `feature_columns` may not be empty, but there is no error with protobuf so it has to be a change from r1.1 to r1.2 that causes this.

Comment: Thank you Maximilian for confirming the error. I add that it seems to be working with python3 using the custom binary protobuf pip from package https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/install/install_linux#protobuf_pip_package_31. (In fact giving AssertionError on my simple example which is the normal behaviour as you remarked.)

Comment: An issue is now live at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10370

Comment: I have updated my solution to include a workaround suggested by cwhipkey on GitHub.

The updated binary protobuf package did **not** help in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Change your numeric locale settings to use a **period** (.) instead of a comma (,) as decimal separator.

### Explanation

In the Google *protobuf* implementation, a locale dependent function is used to convert float to strings in [`FloatToBuffer()`](https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc#L1376).

This becomes a problem when information from a plugin library is extracted automatically.

In your case, it is the sequence

```
eye_separation: float = 2.5
```

at offset *0xa3b4* in `emphasized _single_image_random_dot_stereograms.so`

After being fed to the parser which uses `FloatToBuffer()`, this comes out:

```
attr {\n'
  name: "eye_separation"\n'
  type: "float"\n'
  default_value {\n'
    f: 2,5\n'
  }\n'
}\n'
```

and then the tokenizer (at `google/protobuf/text_format.py`) gets confused by the `,` in the default value and thinks that `5` is a separate field.

A bug report is live at [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10370) and so this will hopefully get fixed, soon.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion changing the locale settings: `System Settings > Language Support > Regional Format > Display numbers, dates and currency amounts in the usual format for: English (United States)` but the problem does not disappear. Is there a particular procedure that I should follow? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For me, running `export LC_ALL=C` worked.

//Erik

Comment: It works also for me. Could you please explain what this command does? Thanks.

Comment: Maximilian discovered that the fix was to change the numeric locale settings to use a period `(.)` instead of a comma `(,)` as decimal separator. `export LC_ALL=C` sets all the locales to the POSIX "standard" one, where the period `(.)` is the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

it's worked solution for it problem:

```
import _locale
_locale.setlocale(_locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

python3.6, freebsd11