# Tensorflow training error in last step

Tags: tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am trying to train my own model for tensorflow object detection, I followed [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-own-object-detector-with-tensorflows-object-detector-api-bec72ecfe1d9) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_mFnvzyLvc&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcNK5GeCQnxYnSSaar2tpku&index=3) tutorials and in last step I tried to run this command

```
> python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --
        pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

but I get this error

```
 > Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 163, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\a
pp.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "train.py", line 91, in main
    FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
  File "C:\Libraries\models-master\research\object_detection\utils\config_util.p
y", line 43, in get_configs_from_pipeline_file
    text_format.Merge(proto_str, pipeline_config)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.
py", line 533, in Merge
    descriptor_pool=descriptor_pool)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.
py", line 587, in MergeLines
    return parser.MergeLines(lines, message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.
py", line 620, in MergeLines
    self._ParseOrMerge(lines, message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.
py", line 635, in _ParseOrMerge
    self._MergeField(tokenizer, message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\text_format.
py", line 703, in _MergeField
    (message_descriptor.full_name, name))
google.protobuf.text_format.ParseError: 195:3 : Message type "object_detection.p
rotos.TrainEvalPipelineConfig" has no field named "shuffle".
```

how can I solve it ?

Comment: What have you tried? The error clearly states that a field is missing, have you checked to ensure it's there?

Comment: in official document and tutorials there isn't any information about relation between 'shuffle' field and tensorflow training steps. I guess there is another problem may be about protobuf version or any other version mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44291072/google-protobuf-text-format-parseerror-when-instantiating-a-tensorflow-model-wit   - which is where you will find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I fix that problem with changing .config file. I used ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config instead of ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config